# How can I obtain the submitted password on users registration with Ultimate Member?

Tags: wordpress, registration

On user registration I am using the action `um_before_save_registration_details` where I add some custom code to save some data to our CRM.

I am able to get all fields of data here but the password seems to be missing, I need this to create a password token for the CRM.

How would I be able to get the password into this action?